# Сделать кнопку только на одной конкретной страничке webview flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, webview

Всем привет, я только начал изучать webview flutter и хочу добавить кнопку на конкретной страничкe в webview. Каким образом можно это реализовать?

Например у меня есть код, webview отображает youtube:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:webview_flutter/webview_flutter.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Welcome to Flutter',
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('Welcome to Flutter'),
        ),
        body: const WebView(
          initialUrl: 'https://www.youtube.com/',
          javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted,
        ),
      )
    );
  }
}
```

Как можно реализовать кнопку только на странице `https://www.youtube.com/feed/library`. Что бы кнопка отображалась только на данной странице, а на других её не было. Помогите реализовать данную кнопку!

Answer (score 0):

Как то так дальше думаю разберешься. В body поменяй на WebViewWidget(url: 'https://www.youtube.com/')

```html
class WebViewWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  final String url;
  const WebViewWidget({Key? key, required this.url}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _WebViewWidgetState createState() => _WebViewWidgetState();
}

class _WebViewWidgetState extends State<WebViewWidget> {
  bool showButton = false;
  bool isLoading = true;
  late WebViewController _webView;

  final Completer<WebViewController> _controllerCompleter =
      Completer<WebViewController>();
  //Make sure this function return Future<bool> otherwise you will get an error
  Future<bool> _onWillPop(BuildContext context) async {
    if (await _webView.canGoBack()) {
      _webView.goBack();
      return Future.value(false);
    } else {
      return Future.value(true);
    }
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    if (Platform.isAndroid) WebView.platform = SurfaceAndroidWebView();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(
      child: Container(
        constraints: BoxConstraints(maxWidth: UIUtil.newsCardWidth(context)),
        child: WillPopScope(
          onWillPop: () => _onWillPop(context),
          child: WebView(
            initialUrl: widget.url',
            gestureNavigationEnabled: true,
            javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted,
            onWebViewCreated: (WebViewController webViewController) {
              _controllerCompleter.future.then((value) => _webView = value);
              _controllerCompleter.complete(webViewController);
            },
            onPageFinished: (String s) {
              setState(() {
                isLoading = false;
              });
            },
            navigationDelegate: (NavigationRequest request) {
              if (request.url.startsWith('https://www.youtube.com/feed/library')) {
                setState(() {
                  showButton = true;
                });
              }
              return NavigationDecision.navigate;
            },
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```